# MVC 4, Model and model render differently

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm not sure why i get this behavior, happy if anyone could pointing me to right source, as i'm not sure what need to google.

View Model

```
public class GeneralDay
{
    public byte tintWeekDay { get; set; }
    public string nvarDayName { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult TargetDay(MODELS.ViewModels.Promotion promotion) {

        var daylist = gd.GeneralDayList();
        foreach (var day in daylist)
        { 
            promotion.targetDay.Add(new MODELS.ViewModels.GeneralDay
            {
                Assigned = promotion.targetDay.FirstOrDefault(x => x.tintWeekDay == day.tintWeekDay) != null,
                nvarDayName = day.nvarDayName,
                tintWeekDay = day.tintWeekDay
            });
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        return PartialView(promotion);
    }
```

View

```
@model GeneralDay
@using XXX.ViewModels;

<fieldset>

 
 //First Part 
@(Model.tintWeekDay)
@(Model.nvarDayName)
@(Model.Assigned)

//Second Part
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.tintWeekDay)    
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.nvarDayName)    
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Assigned) 

</fieldset>
```

The above display these result , why different result?

First Part

> 1 Sunday False

Second Part

> tintWeekDay
>
> nvarDayName
>
> Assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the first part you render the value of the model properties.

@(Model.tintWeekDay) renders 1 to the output.

But @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tintWeekDay) renders the (nonexisting) label for this field, NOT the value)

Use the DisplayAttribute to change the field labels in the model.

Example:

```
public class GeneralDay
{
    [Display(Description = "Day of week")]
    public byte tintWeekDay { get; set; }
    public string nvarDayName { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm new in mvc. a bit confuse. If i like to display value base on 2nd method how could i achieve this? and i like to display a list of checkbox for user to check.

Comment: Ok, found the way to display, i should do this, any better way than this?
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.tintWeekDay)    
    @(Model.nvarDayName)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Assigned)

Comment: @HtmlHiddenFor creates a <input type="hidden" /> element in the rendered HTML. Your question is not really clear about what you exect.

Answer (score 1):

Well the following prints values..

```
//First Part 
@(Model.tintWeekDay)
@(Model.nvarDayName)
@(Model.Assigned)
```

and the following is creating labels

```
//Second Part
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.tintWeekDay)    
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.nvarDayName)    
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Assigned)
```

Since you haven't used the [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx), the `LabelFor`  is just printing the variable name.

Maybe you wanted to use:

```
//Second Part
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tintWeekDay)    
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.nvarDayName)    
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Assigned)
```